# Passing String[] which contains jsonobject values to next activity via putExtra

Tags: android

im fetching image name  from Jsonarray

```
imagename[i] = obj.getString("org_image_name");
```

now i want to pass imagename[] to next activity.i'm calling intent inside an onclick called select

```
   Intent in=new Intent(Album_Display.this,Album_Select.class);

in.putExtra("category_name", category);
in.putExtra("album_id", selected);
in.putExtra("org_image_name", imagename[i]);


startActivity(in);
```

}

i know this is not the right code.

```
in.putExtra("org_image_name", imagename[i]
 please help
```

Comment: do you want to pass the whole array or just one name?

Comment: want to pass the whole`imagename[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass the array without converting it to an arraylist array here is the code

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray("org_image_name", imagenameList);
Intent i=new Intent(Album_Display.this,Album_Select.class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

to receive

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Comment: `Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        array=b.getStringArray("org_image_name"); `

Comment: i want to post array so that i can show it in my backend.   how will i put this value in          `@Override
                protected Map<String, String>getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("sel_img", sel);
                    params.put("uid", Datas.Uid);
                    params.put("category_name", category);
                    params.put("album_id", selected);
                    params.put("org_image_name", String.valueOf(array));
                    return params;
                }`

Comment: hi I don't know about back end but most times i send a json string [{},{}]

Answer (score 0):

you can pass ArrayLists as intent:

```
in.putStringArrayListExtra("org_image_name",imagenameList);
```

you only have to save your array to a List with

```
List<String> imagenameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(imagename));
```

so, your complete code should be simimlar to

```
List<String> imagenameList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(imagename));
in.putStringArrayListExtra("org_image_name",imagenameList);
```

Comment: how to getintent in receiving end.

Comment: you can get your List<String> back via in.getStringArrayListExtra("org_image_name"). This can be transformed back to array.. I am not sure if there is a function for it, otherwise you have to loop through the list and save it in a new array